Find the spectrum of $(Af)(s) = \int _0 ^1 K(s,t)f(t)dt $ where $K(s,t)=\max\{s,t\}$

Find the spectrum of operator $(Af)(s) = \int _0 ^1 K(s,t)f(t)dt $ on $L_2([0,1])$, where $K(s,t)=\max\{s,t\}$ and prove it is adjoint.

I did manage to show it is self-adjoint for $\overline{K(s, t)}=K(t, s)$. I saw a solution claiming because K is compact, the spectrum is made of $\{0\}$ and an at most countable set $A$ of eigenvalues, and that when $A$ is infinite, $0$ is the only limit point of $A$.
In this regard,  I manage to calculate it and prove that for any $\lambda \neq 0$ there exsits $f$ s.t $Af=\lambda f$. But that does not align with the claim for any $\epsilon$ there is a finite number of eigenvalues s.t $|\lambda |>\epsilon$
My calculation for the spectrum involves deriving $Af=\lambda f$ twice and solving.

Here is more or less what you one can do (I leave the details to the OP):
Presumably the space of definition is $L_2([0,1])$.

As for the self-adjointness of $A$:
$$\langle Af,g\rangle =\int^1_0\Big(\int^1_0 (t\vee s)\,f(t)\,dt\Big)\overline{g(s)}\,ds\int^1_0 f(t)\overline{\Big(\int^1_0 (t\vee s)g(s)\,ds\Big)}\,dt=\langle f, Ag\rangle$$

Observe that $A$ is in fact a compact operator (it is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, see also here).

As $L_2([0,1])\subset L_1([0,1])$, it follows from
$$Af(s)=\int^s_0+\int^1_s (t\vee s) f(t)\,dt= s\int^s_0 f(t)\,dt+\int^1_st\,f(t)\,dt
$$
that $Af$ is a.s. differentiable on $[0,1]$.
If $\lambda\in\sigma(A)\setminus\{0\}$, then $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$
\begin{align}
\lambda f(s)=s\int^s_0f(t)\,dt+\int^1_stf(t)\,dt\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
It follows that $f$ is twice differentiable and
$$\lambda f''(s)=f(s)$$
The general solution to this differential equation is
$$
f_\lambda(s)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcr} c_1 e^{\tfrac{s}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}+c_2e^{-\tfrac{s}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} &\text{if} & \lambda>0\\
c_1 \cos\big(\tfrac{s}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}\big)+c_2\sin\big(\tfrac{s}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}\big) &\text{if} & \lambda<0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Plug this into \eqref{one} and see what possibles solutions for $\lambda$ (if any) yield a solution $f_\lambda$ to the equation $(A-\lambda)f_\lambda=0$.

$\lambda<0$. Since
$$s \int^s_0  \cos(\tfrac{t}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}) \,dt + \int^1_s t  \cos(\tfrac{t}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}})\, dt - \lambda  \cos(\tfrac{s}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}) = \sqrt{|\lambda|}\sin(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}) -\lambda\cos(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}})$$
and
$$
s \int^s_0  \sin(\tfrac{t}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}) dt + \int^1_s t \sin(\tfrac{t}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}) dt - \lambda \sin(\tfrac{s}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}) = \sqrt{|\lambda|} (\sqrt{|\lambda|} \sin(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}) - \cos(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}})) + \sqrt{|\lambda|}s
$$
we see that in this case, solutions to \eqref{one} are of the form $f_\lambda(s)= a\cos(\tfrac{s}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}})$ with
$$  \sqrt{|\lambda|}\sin(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}) -\lambda\cos(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}})=0$$
that is, all $\lambda<0$ such that
$$\cot\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}\big)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\lambda|}}$$
which yields a sequence $\lambda_n<0$ with $\lambda_n\nearrow0$,

Similarly, for $\lambda>0$, it can be seen that all solutions to \eqref{one} are of the form
$$f_\lambda(s)=a\cosh\big(\frac{s}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\big)$$
where
$$
\sinh\big(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\big)-\sqrt{\lambda}\cosh\big(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\big)=0$$
This has a unique solution $a\approx 0.694817\ldots$.

I leave it to the OP to check that $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue.


